# Minimal Polynomial of $i\sqrt[4]{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

I see that $$i\sqrt[4]{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})=\{a+b\sqrt[4]{2}:a,b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$$ And so the minimal polynomial has degree $\deg(m_{i\sqrt[4]{2}})\neq 1$. 
Let $\alpha=i\sqrt[4]{2}$, from here I do $$ \alpha^2 = -\sqrt{2} = -(\sqrt[4]{2})^2$$

Here is where I'm not sure what I'm doing is correct:
\begin{equation}
    -(\sqrt[4]{2})^2 = (\underbrace{-\sqrt[4]{2}}_{\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})}) \cdot 
    \underbrace{\sqrt[4]{2}}_{\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})} \hspace{2cm} (1)
\end{equation}
so I can say that $$-(\sqrt[4]{2})^2\in 
    \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}) \hspace{3.73cm} (2)$$ and from here, that $$ m_{i\sqrt[4]{2}}=x^2+(\sqrt[4]{2})^2 \text{ over } \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$$

Then I argue that because $x^2+(\sqrt[4]{2})^2$ is an Eisenstein polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ $\Rightarrow$ $x^2+(\sqrt[4]{2})^2$ is irreducible $\Rightarrow$ $x^2+(\sqrt[4]{2})^2$ is the minimal polynomial $m_{\alpha}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$.

My only actual question is if step $(1)$ and $(2)$ really are correct in this framework. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you know that $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$, but $\alpha^{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$, then it is clear that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ has degree two, because there you have found a polynomial of degree two that vanishes on $\alpha$, but no polynomial of degree one does.

Also, write $\beta = \sqrt[4]{2}$. Then
$$\mathbb{Q}(\beta)=\{a_{0} + a_{1} \beta + a_{2} \beta^{2} + a_{3} \beta^{3} : a_{i} \in \mathbb{Q}\}$$
has degree four over $\mathbb{Q}$. So you see that $\alpha^{2} = - \beta^{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$.

Comment: Okay thank you, I just needed the reassurance for those steps, very much appreciated!!!